# Creating chat commands properly with Socket.IO

Tags: javascript, node.js, server, chat, socket.io

I am developing a chat program ([mountreus-chat](http://painless.montreus.com:3030/room/900/) and [GitHub](https://github.com/gtomitsuka/montreus-chat)) in Node.js using Socket.io and my code looks awful. I'm starting to use commands and now it's even worse.

Here's a code snippet (you can find every detail on the Github repo):

```
io.on('connection', function(socket){
      if(socketConnections().length <= 1024){
        socket.username = socket.handshake.query.username;
        socket.toString = function(){return this.name};
        socket.join(socket.handshake.query.room);
        socket.on('postName', function(username){
                socket.username = username;
                });
        var socketsConnected = socketConnections(socket.handshake.query.room, "/");
        io.emit('connections', socketsConnected.length + 1);
        socket.on('chat message', function(msg){
            var markedMessage =  markdown.renderInline(msg.message);
            var messageDate = moment(msg.date).format("LT, D/M");
            var firstWord = markedMessage.substr(0, markedMessage.indexOf(" "));
            if(msg.message !== "/help"){
            if(firstWord === "/broadcast"){
            var finalMessage = markedMessage.substr(markedMessage.indexOf(" ") + 1);
             var messageToBeSent = '<p class="alignLeft"> BROADCAST: ' + finalMessage + '</p><p class="alignRight">' + messageDate + '</p>';
            }else if(firstWord === "/bot-say"){
                var finalMessage = markedMessage.substr(markedMessage.indexOf(" ") + 1);
                var messageToBeSent = '<p class="alignLeft"> Chat bot: ' + finalMessage + '</p><p class="alignRight">' + messageDate + '</p>';
            }else{
            var messageToBeSent = '<p class="alignLeft">' + escapeHTML(msg.username) + ': ' + markedMessage + '</p><p class="alignRight">' + messageDate + '</p>';
            }
            if(messageToBeSent.length <= 8192){
                  if(!verifyEmptyness(msg.message)){
                    io.to(socket.handshake.query.room).emit('chat message', messageToBeSent);
                  }else{
                  socket.emit('chat message', 'PM: Sorry, you cannot send empty messages.');
                  }
                }else{
                  socket.emit('chat message', 'PM: Oops! You cannot send messages longer than 8192 characters. Sorry!');
                }
            }else{
                socket.emit('chat message', 'Montreus Chat - v1.3.3<br>Available commands:<br>/help - Display help commands<br>/bot-say &lt;message&gt; - Give something for the bot to say!<br>/broadcast &lt;message&gt; - Broadcast a message');
            }
        });
      socket.on('users', function(){
                var socketsConnected = socketConnections(socket.handshake.query.room, "/");
                io.to(socket.handshake.query.room).emit('connections', socketsConnected.length + 1);
                });
      socket.on('disconnect', function(){
                var socketsConnected = socketConnections(socket.handshake.query.room, "/");
                io.to(socket.handshake.query.room).emit('connections', socketsConnected.length + 1);
                });
      }else{
      socket.emit('chat message', 'PM: Sorry, we cannot allow more than 1024 connections in the server');
      socket.emit('chat message', 'PM: Disconnecting! Try again later.');
      socket.emit('connections', 'You are not connected.');
      socket.disconnect();
      }
      });
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can gain a lot of readability by formatting the code (every decent editor will do a passable job at this with a single keystroke) and extracting several small functions (refactoring). I'll start with this but only extract the reusable functions.

> Note: I assumed you can emit the initial connection count after binding the commands. If not, move the first call to `emitConnectionCount` inside `setupSocket`.

```
io.on('connection', function (socket) {
    if (socketConnections().length <= 1024) {
        setupSocket();
        emitConnectionCount();
    } else {
        disconnect();
    }

    function setupSocket() {
        socket.username = socket.handshake.query.username;
        socket.toString = function () {
            return this.name
        };
        socket.join(socket.handshake.query.room);
        socket.on('postName', handleUsername);
        socket.on('chat message', handleMessage);
        socket.on('users', emitConnectionCount);
        socket.on('disconnect', emitConnectionCount);
    }

    function disconnect() {
        emitToUser('PM: Sorry, we cannot allow more than 1024 connections in the server');
        emitToUser('PM: Disconnecting! Try again later.');
        emitToUser('You are not connected.', 'connections');
        socket.disconnect();
    }

    function handleUsername(username) {
        socket.username = username;
    }

    function handleMessage(msg) {
        var markedMessage = markdown.renderInline(msg.message);
        var messageDate = moment(msg.date).format("LT, D/M");
        var firstWord = markedMessage.substr(0, markedMessage.indexOf(" "));
        var messageToBeSent;
        var finalMessage;
        if (msg.message === "/help") {
            emitToUser('Montreus Chat - v1.3.3<br>Available commands:<br>/help - Display help commands<br>/bot-say &lt;message&gt; - Give something for the bot to say!<br>/broadcast &lt;message&gt; - Broadcast a message');
        } else if (firstWord === "/broadcast") {
            finalMessage = markedMessage.substr(markedMessage.indexOf(" ") + 1);
            messageToBeSent = '<p class="alignLeft"> BROADCAST: ' + finalMessage + '</p><p class="alignRight">' + messageDate + '</p>';
        } else if (firstWord === "/bot-say") {
            finalMessage = markedMessage.substr(markedMessage.indexOf(" ") + 1);
            messageToBeSent = '<p class="alignLeft"> Chat bot: ' + finalMessage + '</p><p class="alignRight">' + messageDate + '</p>';
        } else {
            messageToBeSent = '<p class="alignLeft">' + escapeHTML(msg.username) + ': ' + markedMessage + '</p><p class="alignRight">' + messageDate + '</p>';
        }
        if (messageToBeSent.length <= 8192) {
            if (!verifyEmptyness(msg.message)) {
                emitToRoom(messageToBeSent);
            } else {
                emitToUser('PM: Sorry, you cannot send empty messages.');
            }
        } else {
            emitToUser('PM: Oops! You cannot send messages longer than 8192 characters. Sorry!');
        }
    }

    function emitToRoom(message, command) {
        io.to(socket.handshake.query.room).emit(command || 'chat message', message);
    }

    function emitToUser(message, command) {
        socket.emit(command || 'chat message', message);
    }

    function emitConnectionCount() {
        var socketsConnected = socketConnections(socket.handshake.query.room, "/");
        emitToRoom(socketsConnected.length + 1, 'connections');
    }
});
```

That's much easier to grok already, but let's tackle that complicated `handleMessage` function next. What are its responsibilities?

- Parse the message to extract an optional command (`/help`, `/broadcast`, and `/bot-say`).
- Handle the help command.
- Fail if the message is empty.
- Format the message using Markdown.
- Embed it into an HTML snippet.
- Fail if the formatted message is too long.
- Emit the formatted message.

Wow, that's a lot of work--too much for a single function. Let's simplify it by extracting functions for emitting the help text and formatting the message.

```
function handleMessage(chat) {
    var message = chat.message;
    if (message === "/help") {
        handleHelp();
    } else {
        var split = message.indexOf(" ");
        var command;
        if (split === -1) {
            command = '/chat';
        } else {
            command = message.substr(0, split);
            message = message.substr(split);
        }
        if (verifyEmptyness(message)) {
            emitToUser('PM: Sorry, you cannot send empty messages.');
        } else {
            var realMessage = formatMessage(command, message, chat.username, moment(chat.date).format("LT, D/M"));
            if (realMessage.length > 8192) {
                emitToUser('PM: Oops! You cannot send messages longer than 8192 characters. Sorry!');
            } else {
                emitToRoom(realMessage);
            }
        }
    }
}

function formatMessage(command, message, user, date) {
    var intro;
    switch (command) {
        case '/broadcast':
            intro = 'BROADCAST';
            break;
        case '/bot-say':
            intro = 'Chat bot';
            break;
        case '/chat':
            intro = escapeHTML(user);
            break;
        default:
            intro = 'UNKNOWN COMMAND';
            message = command;
            break;
    }
    return '<p class="alignLeft"> ' + intro + ': ' + message + '</p><p class="alignRight">' + date + '</p>';
}

function handleHelp() {
    sendToUser(
        'Montreus Chat - v1.3.3'
        + '<br>Available commands:'
        + '<br>/help - Display help commands'
        + '<br>/bot-say &lt;message&gt; - Give something for the bot to say!'
        + '<br>/broadcast &lt;message&gt; - Broadcast a message'
    );
}
```

That's better, but `handleMessage` is still doing too much. I don't like that it has to parse the original message, check for an empty chat message, and send the formatted message if it's not too long. Let's extract the parsing first.

```
function handleMessage(chat) {
    if (chat.message === '/help') {
        handleHelp();
    } else {
        var parsed = parseMessage(chat.message);
        if (verifyEmptyness(parsed.message)) {
            emitToUser('PM: Sorry, you cannot send empty messages.');
        } else {
            var message = formatMessage(parsed.command, parsed.message, chat.username, moment(chat.date).format("LT, D/M"));
            if (message.length > 8192) {
                emitToUser('PM: Oops! You cannot send messages longer than 8192 characters. Sorry!');
            } else {
                emitToRoom(chat, command, message);
            }
        }
    }
}

function parseMessage(message) {
    var split = message.indexOf(' ');
    if (split === -1 || message.charAt(0) !== '/') {
        return {command: '/chat', message: message};
    } else {
        return {command: message.substr(0, split), message: message.substr(split)};
    }
}
```

If you don't mind formatting an empty message that won't be sent, you can extract the format/check/send logic to yet another function.

```
function handleMessage(chat) {
    if (chat.message === '/help') {
        handleHelp();
    } else {
        handleChat(chat);
    }
}

function handleChat(chat) {
    var parsed = parseMessage(chat.message);
    var formatted = formatMessage(parsed.command, parsed.message, chat.username, moment(chat.date).format("LT, D/M"));
    if (verifyEmptyness(parsed.message)) {
        emitToUser('PM: Sorry, you cannot send empty messages.');
    } else if (formatted.length > 8192) {
        emitToUser('PM: Oops! You cannot send messages longer than 8192 characters. Sorry!');
    } else {
        emitToRoom(chat, command, formatted);
    }
}
```

Here's the final product (after a little reorganization) for ease of understanding and discussion:

```
io.on('connection', function (socket) {
    if (socketConnections().length > 1024) {
        disconnect();
    } else {
        setupSocket();
        emitConnectionCount();
    }

    function disconnect() {
        emitToUser('PM: Sorry, we cannot allow more than 1024 connections in the server');
        emitToUser('PM: Disconnecting! Try again later.');
        emitToUser('You are not connected.', 'connections');
        socket.disconnect();
    }

    function setupSocket() {
        socket.username = socket.handshake.query.username;
        socket.toString = function () {
            return this.name
        };
        socket.join(socket.handshake.query.room);
        socket.on('postName', handleUsername);
        socket.on('chat message', handleMessage);
        socket.on('users', emitConnectionCount);
        socket.on('disconnect', emitConnectionCount);
    }

    function handleUsername(username) {
        socket.username = username;
    }

    function handleMessage(chat) {
        if (chat.message === '/help') {
            handleHelp();
        } else {
            handleChat(chat);
        }
    }

    function handleHelp() {
        sendToUser(
            'Montreus Chat - v1.3.3'
            + '<br>Available commands:'
            + '<br>/help - Display help commands'
            + '<br>/bot-say &lt;message&gt; - Give something for the bot to say!'
            + '<br>/broadcast &lt;message&gt; - Broadcast a message'
        );
    }

    function handleChat(chat) {
        var parsed = parseMessage(chat.message);
        var formatted = formatMessage(parsed.command, parsed.message, chat.username, moment(chat.date).format("LT, D/M"));
        if (verifyEmptyness(parsed.message)) {
            emitToUser('PM: Sorry, you cannot send empty messages.');
        } else if (formatted.length > 8192) {
            emitToUser('PM: Oops! You cannot send messages longer than 8192 characters. Sorry!');
        } else {
            emitToRoom(chat, command, formatted);
        }
    }

    function parseMessage(message) {
        var split = message.indexOf(' ');
        if (split === -1 || message.charAt(0) !== '/') {
            return {command: '/chat', message: message};
        } else {
            return {command: message.substr(0, split), message: message.substr(split)};
        }
    }

    function formatMessage(command, message, user, date) {
        var intro;
        switch (command) {
            case '/broadcast':
                intro = 'BROADCAST';
                break;
            case '/bot-say':
                intro = 'Chat bot';
                break;
            case '/chat':
                intro = escapeHTML(user);
                break;
            default:
                intro = 'UNKNOWN COMMAND';
                message = command;
                break;
        }
        return '<p class="alignLeft"> ' + intro + ': ' + message + '</p><p class="alignRight">' + date + '</p>';
    }

    function emitConnectionCount() {
        emitToRoom(socketConnections(socket.handshake.query.room, "/").length + 1, 'connections');
    }

    function emitToRoom(message, command) {
        io.to(socket.handshake.query.room).emit(command || 'chat message', message);
    }

    function emitToUser(message, command) {
        socket.emit(command || 'chat message', message);
    }
});
```

The main benefits of this version over the original are

- Short functions with descriptive names make it easier to understand the program in small pieces and verify its correctness.
- Repeated code has been deduplicated with reusable functions with sane defaults.
- Separating responsibilities into functions allows each function to live at the same abstraction level. For example, `handleMessage` is only concerned with detecting `/help` or passing off to `handleChat` while the latter is only concerned with checking for a valid message. Likewise for `parseMessage` and `formatMessage`: they are both at even lower abstraction levels.
- Splitting the functions also allowed reusing variable names across functions to avoid wordy repetition such as `markedMessage`, `finalMessage`, and `messageToBeSent`.

Here are some suggested improvements:

- Add JSDoc documentation to each function that requires further explanation, especially those that take parameters. It would also be good to document the `chat` object passed to `handleMessage`.
- Find better names for `handleChat` and `handleMessage`. I would reserve `handle` for functions bound to commands, though `handleHelp` does make sense. Naming can be tough at times, but a good name goes a long way. Don't be afraid of longer names like `formatAndSendMessage` to remove confusion.
- Consider extracting `sendMessage(original, formatted)` from `handleChat` so the latter doesn't do any parsing, formatting, length-checking, or sending but merely ties those all together.